# Retrieve user country through Facebook Android Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an Android application where the user can use his facebook credentials and I list some of his informations like the location. However, I noticed the format of location is something like "location:{id:335457, name: City, State}". I'd like to know if there's a way to also retrieve the user country. I saw the Facebook FQL could help, but, on current SDK version, it is deprecated. My call to the API method:

```
new Request(session, params, null, HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
           // treats the response
        }
    }).executeAsync();
```

I also looked for something, but without success in my case. I'm using the latest Facebook Android SDK available.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `location` **field** of the user is set manually and does not neccessarily mean that he's currently in that location. It's meant to be the current *living* location.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/#fields

The call would be

```
/me?fields=id,location
```

What's returned is a `page_id`, for which's location you can query for with

```
/{page_id}?fields=id,location
```

The `location` object contains a `country` field.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. I'm almost getting the information I need, but, when trying to call the /page_id I receive this error: "Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {page_id}". Would you know why this happens? I'm looking for something, but without success so far.

Comment: It's all in my answer! For sure you Need to replace {page_id} with the id you got first request

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry for that :~ So, I tried it here and it's working. Thank you. However, the field country is not available. I only get the latitude and longitude informations on Location object. But, it is going to help me anyway. Once again, thank you.