# How to retrieve user country using facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve the logged in user country, and insert it into a div.
I succeed making it with the user Name, Gender and Age range, but somewhy I can't retrieve the country.
Here is my code:

```
  function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me?fields=name,email,gender,age_range,picture,country', function (response) {
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response.name + ",";
  document.getElementById('status1').innerHTML = response.gender + ",";
  document.getElementById('status2').innerHTML = (response.age_range.min) + "-" + (response.age_range.min + 1) + " years old";
  document.getElementById('status3').innerHTML = response.country;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379382/retrieve-user-country-through-facebook-android-graph-api)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe the parameter you are looking for is `location` instead of country.

```
/me?fields=name,email,gender,age_range,picture,location
```

In order to query this data, you'll need your users to grant you the [`user_location` permission.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference-user_location)

This will give you value of the user submitted field - take note that this parameter might not always be populated since it depends on the user actually submitting this information - if they have not provided it - you will not be able to retrieve it.

The object will look something like this:

```
  "location": {
    "id": "112604772085346",
    "name": "Ramat Gan"
  },
```

Once you have the location object (which will most likely be a page), you can query that object to retrieve the country:

```
/112604772085346?fields=location
```

This will give you more information including the country.

```
{
  "location": {
    "city": "Ramat Gan",
    "country": "Israel",
    "latitude": 32.0833,
    "longitude": 34.8167,
    "zip": "<<not-applicable>>"
  },
  "id": "112604772085346"
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [vchatbot's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32073757/558021), @Idan - looks like there is a way to do this with only one request to the API - much better :P

Comment: It is posible to get the ISO code for the country in facebook? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1

Comment: @user1253414 - I don't think that Facebook provides countries by ISO codes. You might need to use an additional step to convert these - perhaps something like this will help - https://github.com/lukes/ISO-3166-Countries-with-Regional-Codes

Comment: @Lix Re your comment, as great as that source is, I've found 40 or so don't provide the country names. So It's bit of a tricky job matching up by name alone.

Answer (score 53):

To complete what [Lix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) said:

You can do it with only one call to Graph API, by calling

`/me?fields=name,email,gender,age_range,picture,location{location}`

Indeed, the location object under the user object is a [Page object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/), which has a [Location object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/location/).

So, this will give you something like this:

```
"location": {
  "location": {
    "city": "Ramat Gan",
    "country": "Israel",
    "latitude": 32.0833,
    "longitude": 34.8167,
    "zip": "<<not-applicable>>"
  }
}
```

This avoids you to make a double call to Graph API.

Comment: `location{location}` is new syntax for me - I obviously haven't been around that much to observe these changes - could you please add a little more explanations about it's usage?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how I can add more explanations about its usage... Is there something you did not understand?

Comment: So I understand here we tried it for 'me' but can I give a user's ID there and get the same?

Comment: I think this `location{location}` is old syntax. If someone is confused by it on **2017**, what worked for me was:  `location.fields(location)`. See this topic for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29274998/2561091

Comment: where is state?

Answer (score 2):

Fields in Fb API are now concatenable, so, for a detailed info of User's location you need:

```
scope="public_profile,user_location"

fields="name,location{location{country, country_code, city, city_id, latitude, longitude, region, region_id, state, street, name}}"
```

Comment: Error: Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_location)

Answer (score 0):

v2.11 query:

```
/me?fields=hometown,location
```

permission:

```
user_hometown
user_location
```

result:

```
{
  "hometown": {
    "id": "XXXXREDACTED",
    "name": "Manila, Philippines"
  },
  "location": {
    "id": "XXXXREDACTED",
    "name": "Manila, Philippines"
  },
  "id": "XXXXREDACTED"
}
```