# How do I retrieve country using Facebook Unity Plugins v6.2.2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

**Environment:**

- Facebook Unity Plugins v6.2.2
- Unity 4.6.8 p1
- GraphAPI 2.4

**Problem**

Using Unity with the above SDK Plugin installed, I enter the following:

```
(public_profile,user_friend,user_location,_user_hometown)
```

However the return does not include the hometown. How can I make it so it returns the correct value?

I have tried the codes on the following page, but was unsuccessful:
[How to retrieve user country using facebook Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046552/how-to-retrieve-user-country-using-facebook-graph-api)

Thanks

FYI, The above command works fine if I use the GraphAPI explorer

Answer (score 1):

Has your app passed the login review process for the extended permissions `user_location` and `user_hometown`?

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/best-practices#loginreview

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. And, no, it hasn't been reviewed yet as it isn't complete. We just want to retrieve the user's country info so that we can display their flag in a score ranking board.

Comment: You can only use those permissions then with admins/testers/developers of the specific app. otherwise, it's not possible to gather those permissions if the app has not been through review. As it's said inthe docs...

Answer (score 0):

After

```
FB.Init(OnInitComplete, OnHideUnity);
```

and

```
FB.Login("'permissions'", LoginCallback);
```

things (by the way you don't need any extra permissions to get country) this code will give you country

```
void Get()
{
    FB.API("me", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, UserCallBack);
}

void UserCallBack(FBResult result)
{
    if (result.Error != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("FB.API result = null");
    }
    else
    {
        var dict = Facebook.MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(result.Text) as IDictionary;
        country = dict["locale"].ToString();
    }
}
```