# How to get country on facebook sdk C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to get the country from facebook with SDK but i don't get it.
If i want to extract the location, i recieve this: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]

i use this to make a query between my app and sdk:
`FB.API("/me?fields=first_name, last_name, location, email, birthday, gender", HttpMethod.GET, StoreVars);`

and this to display `Debug.Log(result.ResultDictionary["location"]);`

but it's not working, if i put on the debug.log at final  "as string" i recieve Null.

Comment: User needs to allow you to share their location data with the app.

Comment: In debug mode i don't need it

Comment: No matter what. user needs to share location with the app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve country using Facebook Unity Plugins v6.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450576/how-do-i-retrieve-country-using-facebook-unity-plugins-v6-2-2)